# Office365 OPP(64bit)環境のExcel VBAでOutlook Mail送信が失敗する。

Tags: excel, vba

タイトルの件、お助けいただきたくお願いします。

32bit環境では正常に動作していた以下のコードが、新しい環境だとエラーとなってしまいます。
参照設定は、Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Libraryをチェック済みです。
olMailItemのプロパティを見るとSubjectは入っていますが、ToとBodyでエラーとなっているようです。またウォッチ式を見るとToとBodyの型がVariant/Integerと表示されています。

なお、Sendメソッドは失敗しますが、Saveまでは動作します。
また、コードは参照設定にしない書き方でも同様の現象が発生しました。
Sendメソッドを実行させる方法を知りたく、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
実行時エラー '287': アプリケーション定義またはオブジェクト定義のエラーです。
```

**コード**

```
Sub S01() '参照設定を使用する場合。

    Dim olAppObj As Outlook.Application
    Dim mailObj As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim toAddress As String

    Set olAppObj = New Outlook.Application
    Set mailObj = olAppObj.CreateItem(olMailItem) '指定するアイテムの種類名＝olMailItem、値＝0

    toAddress = "********@*****"

    With mailObj
        .To = toAddress
        .Subject = "*****"
        .Body = "*****"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    End With

    mailObj.Send

    Set olAppObj = Nothing
    Set mailObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: 新しい環境ということですので、確認ですが、もちろんOutlookはインストールされていますよね。

Comment: 池田様、コメントありがとうございます。Outlookはインストールできており、オブジェクトも作れています。Subjectは入るのですが、TOとBodyでエラーが生じ、Sendを実行できないようです。なお、VBAでドラフトしたメールを手動で送信することは可能です。ToとBodyをウォッチ式でみたところ、型がVariant/Integerと表示されているのが気になっています。

Comment: `Body`に関しては`BodyFormat`の設定を先に行って、その後に`Body`ではなく`HTMLBody`にHTMLの形式で内容を設定してみてはどうでしょう？[MailItem.BodyFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat), [Outlook does not render html content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18627436/9014308)。`To`の方は、`Recipients`の`Add`と`Resolve`に変えてみるとか？[MailItem.To](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.to), [Recipients.Add](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add), [Recipient.Resolve](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve)

Answer (score 1):

コメントありがとうございます。
諸々の手段を試しましたが、どうしてもダメだったので、職場の管理担当部署へ問い合わせたところ、独自のセキュリティ設定が邪魔しているようでした。
ｺｰﾄﾞ自体はおそらく問題なく、自社の環境の問題でした。
大変お騒がせいたしまして、申し訳ございません。